# What does ":root" mean in the output of rake routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I run

```
rake routes
```

I see the following:

```
POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles/comments"}
```

This makes perfect sense.  It means if I make a post request to a url of the form /articles/1234/comments, it runs the create action of the controller in articles/comments_controller.rb with the id paramater set as 1234.

But then I see this line also:

```
/article/:id/:action     {:root=>"article", :controller=>"article/article", :title=>"Article"}
```

And I'm not sure what the ":root" means.  Can someone please explain?

EDIT:

I'm using Rails 2.3.18.

Here is the relevant line in the routes.rb file

```
#routes.rb
map.connect '/article/:id/:action', :controller => 'article/article', :root => 'article', :title => 'Article'
```

Comment: copy your routes.rb too

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What version of rails are you using, please?

Answer (score 1):

Like `:title`, it's just another key,value that gets merged into the params hash.

From http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController/Routing ( Defaults routes and default parameters)

> More formally, you can include arbitrary parameters in the route,
> thus:
>
> map.connect ':controller/:action/:id', :action => 'show', :page =>
> 'Dashboard'
>
> This will pass the :page parameter to all incoming
> requests that match this route.

It doesn't have any additional meaning in Rails.  My guess is that your app is using it for breadcrumbs or something similar.